# Is there any good resources for T4 (Text Templating framework from Microsoft)?

Tags: t4

Anything would be good. Exemples, best practices, samples, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hanselman just blogged on this yesterday, he has a huge list of links:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Hanselman post links to this, but just in case: Rob Conery also just recently blogged on this and as usual, it's excellent:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/make-visual-studio-generate-your-repository/

Comment: It seems like this link gives a 404 now. Anyone know of an alternate location?

Answer (score 2):

For my money, the definitive source of good quality information on T4 can be found at http://www.olegsych.com/

With the basics beginning here -> http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/

Answer (score 1):

I find [Clarius's T4 Editor](http://www.t4editor.net/) really helpful.  It adds syntax highlighting, IntelliSense, and project items for T4 to Visual Studio.  There are also demo videos on the website.  There is a free Community edition, and an enhanced, non-free edition which also does C# syntax highlighting.

Comment: It seems like this link is down. Anyone know if it's temporary or know of an alternate location?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to check out the ["T4 Templates" course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=t4-templates) delivered by pluralsight. It covers the following topics:

- Introduction to T4
- T4 Building Blocks
- Extended T4
- Real-world examples
- Troubleshooting and debugging

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is also another [T4 Editor by Tangible](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/Download_T4Editor_Plus_ModelingTools.html) that seems more than just a T4 Editor but also includes some modeling tools.